# reversing sub arrays with nested loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-loops, sub-array

I wants to reverse the array with sub arrays with nested loops. I do not wants to use the reverse function. But every-time I do that I get this a type-error.
anyways here is my code

```
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];


for(let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    for (let j = arr[i].lenght - 1; j > 0; j--)
      {
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
      }
  }
```

The result should be 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 but instead I get nothing blank.

Comment: can you share the snippet of the error message?

Comment: you do not loop to the start, missing zero for `i` and you have at least a typo `lenght`, which should read `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

let result = arr
  .reduce((prev, current) => {
    return [...prev, ...current];
  }, [])
  .reduce((prev, current) => {
    return [current, ...prev];
  }, []);

console.log("result is", result);
```

You can use this also, using reduce
let me know if it works for you or not

Answer (score 2):

You had a typo in the word `length` and also it should be `>= 0`

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];


for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (let j = arr[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: turns out I do not have write [i] with it. the rest are the same.

Comment: It works for me and in my opinion it is the best solution for this question because it shows how to display each value in subarrays with a **nested loop**.